# Chainlink VRF or RANDAO?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

```
    bytes9 private _randomness;

    function getRandomness() public view returns (uint256) {
        return uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(_randomness, address(this))));
    }
    
     modifier updateRandomness() {
        bytes32 randomness = _randomness;
        assembly {
            // Pick any of the last 256 blocks psuedorandomly for the blockhash.
            // Store the blockhash, the current `randomness` and the `coinbase()`
            // into the scratch space.
            mstore(0x00, blockhash(sub(number(), add(1, byte(0, randomness)))))
            // `randomness` is left-aligned.
            // `coinbase()` is right-aligned.
            // `difficulty()` is right-aligned.
            // After the merge, if [EIP-4399](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4399)
            // is implemented, the randomness will be determined by the beacon chain.
            mstore(0x20, xor(randomness, xor(coinbase(), difficulty())))
            // Compute the new `randomness` by hashing the scratch space.
            randomness := keccak256(0x00, 0x40)
        }
        _randomness = bytes9(randomness);
        _;
    }

    function generateNFT() external updateRandomness {
        uint256 randomNum = getRandomness();
        uint256 remaining = MAX_SUPPLY - totalSupply();
        uint256 newId = (randomNum % remaining);
        // ...
    }
```

seems like after the merge, getting a solid random value might be feasible.

this could be a good replacement for chainlink vrf?

Comment: It's still not random though, since you can calculate random numbers based on the beacon chain.

Comment: oh wow it's patrick! :) do you mind elaborating your answer a bit please?

Comment: Sure! Well let's look at it like this, where are you getting your `_currentRandomNum ` value from?

Comment: I edited and added more codes i'm using. So basically each time user is triggering `generateNFT()` it will update `_randomness` to a new value. I read the eip-4399 doc and thought this can be a good fit for randomly generating nfts. Of course for lottery or contracts linked with monetary value depended on randomness, i'd still go with chainlink vrf tho.

Comment: PREVRANDO's random seed calc is by epoch basis, which means the [entropy within 2 epochs is low or even predictable.](https://github.com/ethereum/annotated-spec/blob/master/phase0/beacon-chain.md#aside-randao-seeds-and-committee-generation). A validator who produces multiple blocks can know what a [future PREVRANDAO](https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/eip-4399-supplant-difficulty-opcode-with-random/7368/29) value is, and therefore random numbers should happen within 2 transactions.  There are a lot of considerations like this.

Comment: thanks! alright i get that point, so even though a validator is selected on a random basis evil ones can still predict the PREVRANDO, but can be prevented when it is happened within 2 transactions? 

It sounds like the validator must be so dedicated and act quickly within 26 seconds :) yeah there is vulnerability to this, but I'd say it's still a viable alternative for not popular nft mint collection which will close its sales within a couple of days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Summary

For pseudorandomness you can use something like [EIP-4399](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4399):

```js
uint256 randomness = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, block.difficulty, block.timestamp)));
```

(You don't even need to use assembly, `difficulty` is directly exposed in solidity)

But for true randomness, you'd need something like [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/subscription/examples/get-a-random-number/).

```js
    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 _requestId, uint256[] memory _randomWords) internal override {
        uint256 randomness = _randomWords[0];
    }
```

### Why is `difficulty` or `PREVRANDAO` pseudo-random in a post-merge ETH?

When a validator is due to propose a block, they face a [fairly minimal penalty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90781/what-is-the-penalty-of-having-eth2-validator-offline) for failing to do so. Given a smart contract that is trying to make itself unpredictable/uncontrollable via `PREVRANDAO`, this option allows them to cheaply bias the behavior of the contract in the following ways.

#### 1. You always need a validator to propose two blocks in a row

`PREVRANDAO`'s value has no [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)) given the `PREVRANDAO` value from the previous block if no block is proposed. When you propose a block, that's a piece of the math equation that `PREVRANDAO` uses to make a random number. So if you don't propose a block, you get a "less" random number.

So users of `PREVRANDAO` would need to check that a validator has provided a block since the last time they called `PREVRANDAO`. Otherwise, they won't necessarily be drawing statistically independent random outputs on successive calls to PREVRANDAO.

This means that the validator committed to proposing a particular block can effectively set the PREVRANDAO value for the next block to two possible values:

- the one which results from its mandated `PREVRANDAO` input value
- whatever `PREVRANDAO` gets deterministically set to if no block is proposed

This choice alone allows validators to influence the random number, no longer making the number random.

Even if the contract does something cleverer, like taking the `PREVRANDAO` output from the first block to be proposed after some height, every validator after that height has the same option. No matter which way the contract tries to access `PREVRANDAO`, the last validator to contribute will always have predictable control over the random output which controls the contract.

These issues don't arise for Chainlink VRF, because the output is deterministic, given the blockhash (just infeasible to compute for anyone who doesn't know the secret key.)

#### 2. Validators can choose to not post if a number is unfavorable

Once again, you still run into this issue from pre-merge. The penalty of not posting a block is almost negligible, so a node might be financially incentivized not to propose blocks in a lottery-type smart contract if the `PREVRAND` value isn't what they want. Enough nodes do this and you run into issues.

Just taking the current `PREVRANDAO` value without looking at recent history gives a validator some control over the output the contract will use, even if it doesn't want to abort, because the validator can decide whether or not the block it proposes contains a transaction which will trigger the use of PREVRANDAO. The only cost involved there is the transaction fee/tip.

#### 3. If all applications use `PREVRANDAO` as their seed

If all applications use `PREVRANDAO` as their seed, in a way, you could "chain" together wins or hacks based on this.

#### More information

There is also an interesting thread on this in the [Ethereum Magicians](https://ethereum-magicians.org/t/eip-4399-supplant-difficulty-opcode-with-random/7368/48) forum.

Comment: The recommendation of combining `block.difficulty` (now the prevrandao value) with `msg.sender` is extremely insecure and could lead to a major vulnerability if anyone chooses to follow the recommendation.

Mixing the two values means that an attacker could completely circumvent the RANDAO randomness by picking an address that leads to their desired outcome depending on the contract.